# Difference between disposable , disposableObservers and composite Disposable

Tags: android, rx-java2

What are the main differences between

- Disposable
- DisposableObservers
- composite Disposable

When to use each one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disposable` is a job which can be canceled.
`CompositeDisposable` is a parent job where you can add a much as cancealble jobs as you like (aka disposables)
As for the `DisposableObserver`, is a job that allows you to cancel it even when you are async mode.

So to be more clear, in order to avoid leaks, you need to make your Rx operations inside these jobs, and manage their cancelation by the Activity/Fragment Lifecycle.

For example:

```
val disposable = Observable.fromCallable().....
compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

On the `onDestroy` method:

```
compositeDisposable.dispose();
```

As for the `DisposableObserver`, refer [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html), I don't have much info

Comment: Number of overridden methods are the defference between `disposable` (4 of them) and `disposableobservers`(3 of them)

Comment: Thank you, I should remeber that :)